# Getting unique values from user input

Tags: python, list, input

How to prevent input same value in a empty list for several times?

**Wrong** example

```
a = [ ]

while  a [ 4 ] ! = None: #ensure in put 5 times

    option = input()

    if option in a: #prevent input same value

        continue  
    else:
        a.append(option)
```

Moreover, if i use dict is better?

And I am not native of English

Comment: so what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `set` if you want to have unique elements collection.

```
a = set()

while len(a) < 5:
    a.add(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

my Current code looks like this:

```
results = list()

amount_of_numbers = int(input("Please enter the amount of Names: "))

while len(results) < amount_of_numbers:
    userNumber = (input("Please input a Name: "))
    if userNumber not in results:
        results.append(userNumber)
    else:
        print ("{} has already been entered".format(userNumber))
print (results)
```

Result:

> > > (executing file "<tmp 2>")
> > > Please enter the amount of Names: 5
> > > Please input a Name: test
> > > Please input a Name: test
> > > test has already been entered
> > > Please input a Name: Test
> > > Please input a Name: Lee
> > > Please input a Name: lee
> > > Please input a Name: leer
> > > ['test', 'Test', 'Lee', 'lee', 'leer']

Comment: Mayank Patel, please don't add *Me too* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29787378)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.